# Ethereum connect apps besides Metamask

Tags: metamask

I am exploring for alternate consumer apps besides Metamask to connect to production Ethereum for end users in Ethereum Dapp. Is there better alternatives available for the same?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there. Can you explain in detail what you mean by "better"? What characteristics do you want a "better" alternative to have?

Comment: You can check the https://web3connect.com/ example and see the alternatives to MetaMask used there.